# Create a time series that sums data on each day D, if D is between the start date and the end date

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My raw data is a dataframe with **three** columns that describe journeys: **quantity**, **start date**, **end date**. My goal is to create a new dataframe with a daily index and **one** single column that shows the **sum of the quantities** of the journeys that were "on the way" each day i.e. sum quantity if day > start date and day < end date.
I think I can achieve this by creating a daily index and then using a *for* loop that on each day uses a *mask* to filter the data, then sums. I haven't managed to make it work but I think that there might actually be a better approach? Below is my attempt with some dummy data...

```
data = [[10, '2020-03-02', '2020-03-27'],
        [18, '2020-03-06', '2020-03-10'],
        [21, '2020-03-20', '2020-05-02'],
        [33, '2020-01-02', '2020-03-01']]
columns = ['quantity', 'startdate', 'enddate']
index = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index,columns)

index2 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-06-01', freq='D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0,index2,'quantities')
for t in index2:
    mask = (df['start']<t) & (df['end']>t)
    df2['quantities'] = df[mask]['quantity'].sum()
```

Comment: what is `quantities`? your second dataframe is not correctly shared. Also, kindly add your expected dataframe output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could create date range for each record, then explode and groupby:

```
data = [[10, '2020-03-02', '2020-03-27'],
        [18, '2020-03-06', '2020-03-10'],
        [21, '2020-03-20', '2020-05-02'],
        [33, '2020-01-02', '2020-03-01']]
columns = ['quantity', 'startdate', 'enddate']
index = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index,columns)

df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['startdate'],x['enddate'],freq='D'), axis=1)
df = df.explode('range')
df.groupby('range')['quantity'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data describes a step function, ie on the 2nd of March (midnight) it increases by a value of 10, and on the 27th of March (midnight) it decreases by 10.

This solution uses a package called [`staircase`](https://staircase.dev) which is built on `pandas` and `numpy` for working with (mathematical) step functions.

**setup**

```
data = [[10, '2020-03-02', '2020-03-27'],
        [18, '2020-03-06', '2020-03-10'],
        [21, '2020-03-20', '2020-05-02'],
        [33, '2020-01-02', '2020-03-01']]
columns = ['quantity', 'startdate', 'enddate']
index = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index,columns)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-06-01', freq='D')

df["startdate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["startdate"])
df["enddate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["enddate"])
```

**solution**

Create a `staircase.Stairs` object (which is to `staircase` as `pandas.Series` is to `pandas`) which represents a step function.  It is as easy as passing the start times, end times, and values, which since your data is in a `pandas.Dataframe` can be done by passing the column names

```
import staircase as sc
sf = sc.Stairs(frame=df, start="startdate", end="enddate", value="quantity")
```

The step function will be composed of left-closed intervals by default.
There are lots of things you can do with step functions including plotting

```
sf.plot(style="hlines")
```

[image]

If you want to just get the value at the start of each day then you can sample the step function like this

```
sf(dates, include_index=True)
```

The result will be a `pandas.Series` indexed by your date range

```
2020-01-01     0
2020-01-02    33
2020-01-03    33
2020-01-04    33
2020-01-05    33
            ..
2020-05-28     0
2020-05-29     0
2020-05-30     0
2020-05-31     0
2020-06-01     0
Freq: D, Length: 153, dtype: int64
```

A more general solution to your problem which includes start and end times at any datetime (not just midnight) and arbitrary bins can be achieved with [slicing and integrating](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/user_guide/slicing.html).

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.